# How to toggle a div only on mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, bootstrap-4, toggle

I'm new to the field so there might be an obvious solution but I'm not seeing it.

I'm trying to create a div that, only on mobile, can be clicked on to show its children. On other screens both parent and children should be visible.
So far I've only managed to create the toggle using some script, and I have no idea on how to target mobile only.

```
<div class="main_div" onclick="myFunction()">
  <h3>Section title</h3>
  <div class="row" id="toggle">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-5 child">content here</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-5 child">content here</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-5 child">content here</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-5 child">content here</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("toggle");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: There are tutorials on this. Generally speaking though, you wouldnt want to nest the content you want to toggle inside the very element you are clicking on.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to make it depending on the screen width. On a mobile device the screen is usually less wide.

I made an example where screens (strictly speaking: viewports) less than 600 hides the toggled block initialy and the title can toggle the visibility.

On screens with a width >600 the block is always visible.

```js
function toggleContent() {
  var toggle = document.getElementById("toggle");
  if (window.innerWidth < 600)
  {
    if (toggle.style.display === "none" || toggle.style.display === "") {
      toggle.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      toggle.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#toggle {
  display: block;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .title {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  #toggle {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main_div" id="main_div">
  <h3 class="title" onclick="toggleContent()">Section title</h3>
  <div class="row" id="toggle">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-5 child">content here</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-5 child">content here</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-5 child">content here</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-5 child">content here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```